# Outlook VBA Autosave Attachments Rule - Downloadstate is zero?

Tags: vba, outlook, imap, email-attachments, autosave

I have a rule which starts a sub in VBA when a new eMail arrives.
The code automatically saves the attachment of the Mail in a specific folder.
This worked fine, as long as..... I reinstalled the system.

I added everything like it was, but now I'm suffering the following problem:
When the rule hits in, the eMail Object always has zero attachments. I was sniffing around a little bit and found out, that the Downloadstate is still zero (header only) when the sub runs.

On the web we can see lots of code snippets around for this functionality but Downloadstate seems never to be a topic. So it wasn't for me in the past!

What is wrong here? Why is the Downloadstate zero when the VBA Sub starts?

I found a little workaround by querying the downloadstate and re-run the procedure again with the same mail item. This loop works fine. Almost on the next run it seems that the message is fully downloaded already... And the procedure takes place like it should. But as i know that it worked fine right before, I just want to get rid of this again...

Can anybody help?

Comment: Might be an outlook setting, check this out: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/412

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I found something like this out as well. The difference is indeed, that the mailboxes are now IMAP where it is not working. I configured it in the previous installation as POP3. I tried, adding the settings you specified. But no luck. I think this might be a bug with Outlook 2010 and IMAP Mailboxes. In this combination the Autosave VBA Code won't work, due to the download of the message seems to be delayed or been done after the code. I changed now everything back to POP3 and now it works fine again.